# Are bubbles in new exterior paint normal?

Tags: paint, exterior

Not happy with the new exterior paint job - it bubbled immediately, and the initial recommendation from the contractor was "don't pop them". We gave it time to settle, but the issue still hasn't been resolved. I am so disappointed in the appearance. I asked the owner if this:

1. Was satisfactory to him as a professional
2. Met current industry standards
3. Was he prepared to do nothing to remedy the situation?

It appears the answer was 'yes' to all. Is it reasonable that I ask again for this to be re-done in the spring when it is warm and dry? Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Those are very good questions you asked the contractor.

The result of the paint job is unacceptable. Besides being unsightly, the paint job will not have the longevity you want or expect, as the bubbles will pop or split on their own, and form a nice little place to hold water against your siding. The bubbling is most likely due to painting on a damp surface.

Answer (score 13):

No, that is not normal, nor satisfactory, nor remotely professional.

It probably occurred from excess moisture present before the paint was applied.  The solution is more work than simply painting:  The blistered paint needs to be stripped, the bare surface prepared thoroughly, including drying—which could be done in winter with a tent and heaters, etc.—and repainting.

I suspect the "professional" who did this cut corners in an effort to improve profit.  Certainly he is not trying to build a list of satisfied customers.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of the board under the paint, you had bare wood exposed allowing moisture to penetrate.  The new paint has sealed the moisture in the wood and has bubbled up in the places where the moisture is trying to escape.  The best remedy is to scrape and repaint the siding during a warm dry period so the moisture can come out of the wood and prevent future bubbles from appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Moisture. My painters always allow several days after power-washing, and then check with a two prong moisture meter.

Answer (score 0):

Paint blister occur for several reasons and (as been mentioned several times) moisture  is one of the causes. If the siding had been not allowed to dry properly after power washing, for instance, and immediately covered with paint the moisture would form a blister as it evaporated. Here are some other causes for paint blistering: applying paint in direct sunlight on a hot (+85 degree) day and applying another coat of paint before the first one has dried completely. The solutions to all of these issues is to re-sand the dried paint until blisters are gone and wait for the wood to dry completely. Afterward prime and finish as usual. BTW: the blisters, as you probably now know, won't be resolved by themselves and will need further attention in the way of preparation work to look acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The blisters if when scrapped or popped show the original paint color then you painter did not prep right. If you pop that bubble and it goes all the way down to the wood you are having a falsity from the original primer finally not being able to hold. Houses that have lap siding and that are older. At some point someone caulked all the laps sealing up the spot where moisture from a he inside of the house is suppose to escape. This is why most bubbles pop up on the sunny side of the home and normally around your kitchen or bathroom walls.  If you notice the place where he was able to scrape because that paint was failing before the job started and he was able to get to bare wood you are probably not having my any issue. In my home town with the new EPA regulations about lead paint and not being able to sand. People simple can't afford to have there homes heat stripped or replace all there siding. Now if it's new siding and your having bubbles then you are probably 95% it is poorly prepped